If $B$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, then is the column space of $B$ and $BB^{'}$ same?
The question:
If $B$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, then is the column space of $B$ and $BB^{'}$ same, where $B^{'}$ is transpose of $B$?
Context:
There was a question that if $ABB^{'} = CBB^{'}$, then show that $AB = CB$. The solution used the fact that the space spanned by columns of $B$ and  $BB^{'}$ are same.
The link to the question
I understand that the column space of XY is a subset of column space of X, but I am not able to see why in the above case, they are equal.

You need to show $\text{rank}(BB') \leq\text{rank}(B)$ is met with equality.  But this is not true in general -- the field you are working over matters quite a bit here.

This works even if $B$ is $m \times n$. We just need to show that, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, there exists some $y \in \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $Bx = BB'y$. To construct such a $y$, we take a tip from linear least squares: we let $y$ minimise $\|B'y - x\|$.
Note that $x - B'y$ lies in the orthogonal complement of the columnspace of $B'$, a well-known fact about metric projections onto subspaces. As such, for any $z \in \Bbb{R}^m$,
$$0 = (B'z)'(x - B'y) = z'(Bx - BB'y).$$
Choosing $z = Bx - BB'y$ shows $\|Bx - BB'y\|^2 = 0$, i.e. $Bx = BB'y$.

Thanks for the answer, could you help me see why $x-B^{'}y$ lies inside the orthogonal complement of the columnspace of $B^{'}$. I am new to this fact. I can follow the rest of the argument. it's very neat.

@Debu Here's an older answer of mine, to a more general problem. You can start from "To see that $x_\infty - x_0 \in V^\perp$..." Here, $x_0$ is $x$, $x_\infty$ is $B'y$, and $V$ is the columnspace of $B'$. If this is too difficult to follow, let me know, and I'll adapt the argument here.

Thanks a lot. I got it.
